# Is there a documented way to use autotools from a nonstandard location?

Tags: thrift, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am trying to build the `thrift` library on a machine with a set of out-of-date autotools installed. I am working without root and am trying to avoid modifying any files owned by root.

I downloaded and built the latest versions of each autotool, but when I tried to use them, I ran into a number of somewhat hardcoded assumptions about the location of other autotools.

For example, in addition to the `PATH` changes, I also had to set the variables `AUTOM4TE_CFG` and `autom4te_perllibdir`, as well as hand-modify a bunch of autotools related configuration files in the `thrift` distribution.

The amount and nature of the effort required to bootstrap a build from autotools living at a nonstandard location appears to be extremely hacky, especially given that the autotools were intended to improve portability.

**Is there a documented way to run the entire set of autotools from nonstandard locations?**

Comment: If you are just trying to build Thrift from a tarball, then you shouldn't need any autotools, let alone recent ones. `./configure`, `make`, and `make install` should do the trick. It's only if you modify files such as `configure.ac` and `Makefile.am` that you would need the autotools.

Comment: @ptomato I am trying to build it from version control.  However the question is broader than thrift.

Comment: Hmm, I've never had any issues at all running with the autotool chain in a subdirectory of  $HOME.  How are you installing everything?  I typically install autoconf, automake, and libtool from git into $HOME/bin and then just run $HOME/bin/autoreconf, letting it use m4 and other tools from the system.  How are you installing the autotools?  (ie, are you just setting --prefix during configure, or are you setting DESTDIR at make time, or something else)

Comment: The problem is using m4 and other tools from the system.  My entire tool chain is out of date including m4.

Comment: So install an up to date m4 and put its location in your PATH before the system version.  I believe that autoconf will set the appropriate variable (M4PATH?) to the version it finds when you run autoconf's configury.

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying I don't know anything about thrift.  Maybe it does weird stuff -- always a possibility with the autotools, as they are quite open-ended.

Second, as far as I know none of this is really documented.  However, it is a logical consequence of the way that the autotools themselves work.

I *do* somewhat routinely run autotools from a personal build.  My situation is not quite as extreme as yours, as I'm able to rely on the system `m4`, but the basic idea is the same.

What I do is download (or check out) the versions of the tools I want.  Then, I build them in order: `autoconf`, then `automake`, then `libtool` if I really think I need it.  For each one, I use the same `--prefix` option when configuring.  I point it to a new directory.  This way, after `make install`, all the tools end up in the same install tree.

This looks something like:

```
cd $src/autoconf-$version
./configure --prefix=/home/tromey/autotools
make && make install
cd ../automake-$version
./configure --prefix=/home/tromey/autotools
make && make install
... libtool if you need it
```

After this, I add `$prefix/bin` to my `PATH`.  Then everything is ready to go.

There are two wrinkles here.

First, if I were in your situation, I would first build `m4` using the same approach -- but I would add the prefix to my `PATH` before building `autoconf`.  This way the `autoconf` build would pick up the correct `m4` executable.

Second, sometimes programs depend on `.m4` files that provide macros and are used by `aclocal`.  On occasion I need to make the odd symlink to a system-provided `.m4` file or some other hack like this to make a build happen.  This is relatively rare though.